# HTML change URL after an action-invoking-URL was processed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, url

I find this problem hard to reword briefly in the title but this is what happens:

A page (domain.com/pages) shows for example a table with rows from the database and for each row I provide a 'Delete' button. This button redirects for example to (domain.com/pages/delete/5) when row with ID 5 is deleted. When loading the page, it recognizes row 5 needs to be deleted, so it does so. Afterwards it continues loading as if (domain.com/pages) was requested. So now the table shows again, with row ID 5 deleted and the URL in the address bar being (domain.com/pages/delete/5). When refreshing it reloads (domain.com/pages/delete/5) but I want it to reload (domain.com/pages).

So in short:

- (domain.com/pages) -> show table
- (domain.com/pages/delete/[id]) -> delete [id] from table -> show table

I don't want a redirect after the second link because I want to minimize redirection and keep site speed high. This *could* be fixed with AJAX calls, but that might complex things unnecessarily. Do I miss an easy way to make this action-invoking-URL just a one timer (ie. not invoked (accidentally) by refreshing)?

Comment: Ajax is indeed a better solution. If not, issue a location.replace("domain.com/pages") from the delete page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to achieve this with the History API:

```
if( history.replaceState) history.replaceState(null,document.title,"/pages");
```

However, if you're interested in performance keep in mind that every time a row gets deleted, you're having to reload the entire table. Instead, you should use AJAX to request that the server delete the row, then use `.removeChild()` to remove the corresponding row from the table.

Comment: The first part is dependent on HTML5. Let's not take it for granted that he is using that. Otherwise, very solid answer. I'd personally recommend Ajax.